# SQL query to find INSERT stored procedures that don't name columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am the last of a large development team, tasked with handing over the large existing system to a new team. As part of the migration, ID columns are being added to every table in the database (even if the table already has one).  The issue is that within the many hundreds of stored procedures, some old INSERTS do not name columns:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (blah, blah, blah)
```

These, of course, break with the new column being added because the number of columns in the table does not match the number in the `INSERT`. I need to alter all of the `INSERT`s.

Not a problem, except first I need to find them. This query returns over 900 results and too many false positives (because it returns `INSERT`s that name the columns and those that don't):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%insert into%' 
  AND OBJECT_NAME(object_id) NOT LIKE 'MSmerge%'
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
```

This one returns a nice small number but misses some I know are bad:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%insert into%' 
  AND definition NOT LIKE '%) value%'
  AND definition NOT LIKE '%)%' + CHAR(10) + '%value%'
  AND definition NOT LIKE '%)%' + CHAR(13) + '%value%'
  AND definition LIKE '%value%' 
  AND OBJECT_NAME(object_id) NOT LIKE 'MSmerge%'
```

Here is part of a stored procedure that last query missed:

```
BEGIN
    IF @someFlag = 1
        INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (@myCode, @myYear, @myMonth, 1, 1, 0)
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (@myCode, @myYear, @myMonth, 1, 0, 1)
END
```

Is there a way to reliably find the stored procedures I need to fix?

Comment: why the first query give you "false postive"? show us example of those

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  It returns all the INSERTS that do name columns and do not need to be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql) is very useful. It not only updates the metadata as documentation says, but does a lot of checks. It can detect a lot of errors in views, stored procedures, triggers and functions.

The following stored procedure calls `sp_refreshsqlmodule` on all sql modules in the database and prints out all errors it finds:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RefreshAllModules]
AS

    DECLARE m CURSOR FOR
    SELECT '[' + s.name + ']'  + '.[' + o.name + ']' AS name, o.type_desc
    FROM 
        sys.sql_modules m
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
            on m.object_id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
            on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE
        m.is_schema_bound = 0
    OPEN m
    DECLARE  @name sysname, @type_desc sysname
    FETCH NEXT FROM m into @name, @type_desc
    WHILE  @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule @name
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            IF  @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
            PRINT  @type_desc + ': ' +  @name
            PRINT ''
        END CATCH
        FETCH NEXT FROM m INTO @name,  @type_desc
    END
    CLOSE m
    DEALLOCATE m
GO
```

For example, imagine you have the following table and stored procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE p
AS
    INSERT INTO T VALUES ('John Doe') 

GO
```

Later, you alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD id int;
```

Now, the stored procedure is invalid. But you can detect it executing `RefreshAllModules`:

```
EXEC RefreshAllModules
```

Which outputs:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition. SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE: [dbo].[p]

Comment: This took a couple minutes to run but it worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is just a guideline, because you need create multiple cte or a `FOR .. LOOP` to calculate those.

Use `CHARINDEX` to find your `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` pairs.

```
i = CHARINDEX ('INSERT INTO', QueryString)   
j = CHARINDEX ('VALUES ', QueryString, i)   
k = CHARINDEX ('(', QueryString, i)
```

So if you don't find a parenthesis `k` between `i` and `j` you have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

1. Restore a backup of the database and USE it.
2. Use database > tasks > generate script to generate DROP and CREATE scripts for all sprocs.
3. Run script. All sprocs that need changing will fail.